# Why isn't the last hierarchy erasing the first one?

Tags: css, sass

My understanding was that when you add some css to any class after another one, the second one will have more hierarchy. However, in this case, the first one is the one that is being applied to my code.

```
#list {

    .list-over {
        margin-bottom: 20px;

        @include media($large-screens) {
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            width: 30%;//This is the one that appears (but I want to be stepped with the other that is next to the next comment)
        }
    }
}

.container {
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 330px;
    padding-right: 0%;

    &.content{
        padding-right: 0%;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    p{
        font-style: italic;
    }

    &.list-over {

        @include media($large-screens) {
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            width: 70%;//This is the one that I’m expecting!
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to apply the !important label, but still it doesn't work the way I'm expecting it.

I need the second width (that is inside .list-over and inside .container) to step over the first, but I can't erase the first.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Need to see the HTML to see how these classes are applied to the markup. If the !important attribute isn't overriding, it's because your 2nd `&.list-over` CSS targeting is missing the mark. Is your markup like this? `#list > .container.list-over` ?

Comment: @bot19 Unfortunately, the HTML is very complex because it belongs to a huge website and I thought I would be confusing to others. Don't you think that the second one should be the one displayed? Does the HTML order have something to do with the hierarchy? Thanks!

Comment: HTML structure is directly related to how you specify your CSS, if the way your target your CSS doesn't match your HTML class structure, your CSS won't apply and since !important isn't working, this is what I suspect you did wrong.

Comment: @bot19 Actually, they are not immediately one after the other. There are some other tags in the middle. Should they be one after the other in order to have '&.list-over' working?

Comment: if you want the 2nd `.list-over` to work, it has to be on the same container as `.container`, what the `&` will output to CSS is `.container.list-over`, meaning in the HTML, it has to look like this to work: `<div class="container list-over">`.

Comment: @bot19 Thank you very much! I'll keep trying to fix it but at least I know that I was wrong about '&' . Also, when you declare classes in the top example #list and add .list-over inside, that means that they should be immediately one after the other? or could be that there are some html elements in the middle?

Comment: Also, it seems like your `#list` is missing the closing `}`, unless you mean the `.container` code to be inside it..? That could also be a problem.

Comment: @bot19 It was missing. I'm sorry about it. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there could be 3 reasons why your styling isn't working.

1. if indentation is any indicator, `.container` class isn't meant to be a child of `#list` id, in which case, your `.list-over` inside `#list` is missing a closing `}`.
2. take care of your HTML structure, it is directly related to how you structure / target your CSS, right now the 2nd `&.list-over` should be a class on the same element containing `.container` class, like this: `<div class="container list-over">`. The `&` joins classes / class-names in SASS/SCSS.
3. under certain HTML structures, the 2nd `&.list-over` doesn't have a higher specificity than your first one under `#list`. See example below, to make it work I had to add `!important`.

Side note: inside `#list`, there could be any number of wrapping elements of `.list-over`. Take care of point 2, otherwise if that isn't the case, then you have to remove `&` from `&.list-over`. You can inspect (Chrome devTools). If the class styling is correctly applied, you can at least see it being overwritten.

HTML structure:

```
<div id="list">
    '#list' element (parent)
    <div>
        'div' element (child)
        <div class="container list-over">
            Element with 'container' and 'list-over' class (grand child)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
#list {
  border: 1px solid green;

  > div { border: 1px solid orange; }

  .list-over {
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
}

.container {
  &.list-over {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
  }
}
```

[Working example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-bohr-xckpf?fontsize=14) (I couldn't do it on SO because not sure how to include SCSS).

If this helps you to fix your issue, please consider accepting this answer :)

Comment: That is an excellent explanation and completely related to the question I asked. Tomorrow, I'll figure out how to accept the answer and do it.

Comment: @loop123123 it's just the tick top-left corner of answer. Would be interested to know how you fix this :)